# How to upload different types of files to SQL and then retrieve them for download with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, yii, download

I'm working on Yii and I want to upload and download some files, I can upload some files to the Documents table in the blob_document field which is blob type, now I've tried doing this to download the files

```
<?
    $file = Documents::model()->findByPk('3');
    $file = $file->blob_document;
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo $file;
    exit;
?>
```

I'm downloading a .txt file which is the correct extension but the content has the name of the file instead of the original text.

Comment: `$file = $file->blob_document;` trashes the file object...

Answer (score 1):

$file->blob_document is only the filename, to get the content, you can use file_get_contents, or better (less memory consumption), readfile() to output the contents of the file.

```
<?php
    $file = Documents::model()->findByPk('3');
    $file = $file->blob_document;
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the content look like inside the database?  Perhaps it is not being inserted properly....

Abstracting SQL, should be a crime ;-)